# How is it technically possible to have a null this pointer in a strack trace?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a core file where the application crashed inside a method which was called on a `NULL`-pointer:

```
class myclass{
    myclass_impl* impl;

    void func();
}

func(){impl->implFunc();}
```

The application crashes since the member impl is NULL. But the stracktrace ends in `myclass_impl::implFunc()` with `*this` beeing `NULL`.

How is that even possible?

Comment: **This is not a duplicate**. The linked question asks what happens when you call a method on a null reference. This question knows (it crashes), but asks why a callstack behaves the way it does.

Comment: @Qix the top answer of the duplicate also answers this question. It's possible because the behaviour is undefined and therefore anything may happen. *Anyhing* includes pointers being null.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. If it's clear that the application crashes, then it's also clear the application is likely to crash somewhere related to the problem at hand.

Comment: @MSalters question is asking how the stacktrace knows what method was called when it crashed if the `this` pointer was `NULL`.

Comment: @Qix: I'm not sure I agree with your interpretatin of the question. Besides, a stack trace is an approximation anyway. It assumes that a function call is instant: either `foo()` is on the call stack or it isn't. In reality, it takes multiple instructions to make a function call, and any of these can cause a segfault. Should `foo()` be shown on the callstack then? Matter of opinion, but in general it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @msalters I find the answer qix gave helpful. how can the instructions during a function call lead to a crash? I would like to get a technical understanding beyond the fact that the standard says it isn't defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the location of the function `implFunc()` is known. It has an address, therefore we know that we're inside it when we look at the call stack.

However, the `this` pointer that was used to call that function is set to `0` (or really, some undefined, but unallocated, value - depending on how it's used).

---

You can think of member methods like functions that take an implicit first argument as the `this` value (in fact, that's [exactly what happens](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245668/where-does-this-go-in-a-x64-thiscall) on many platforms). You don't *need* pointers to be valid in order to call a function. The call will at least reach the function, and thus place the function's location on the call stack (which is what is used to generate a backtrace), and what happens *inside* the function is up to whether or not you dereference that pointer.

Your scenario, then, means you called that function with the implicit first parameter being a `NULL` pointer. The function call *itself* succeeded, but the pointer being used *inside* the function (method) failed because you dereferenced a null pointer.